# How do I retrieve photos from Photos Library with PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers:) in Swift 5.2?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photokit, phphotolibrary

I'm trying to retrieve photos in Photo Library with `asset.localIdentifier` but `PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers:options:)` says:

> `<extracting data from value failed>`

and I have an error:

> "[core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""

Here is how I get identifiers:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if picker.sourceType == .photoLibrary {
        if let imageURL = info[.referenceURL] as? URL {
            let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageURL], options: nil)
            guard let asset = result.firstObject else {return}
            if let name = selectedProject?.name {
                photo.name = name
                photo.identifier = asset.localIdentifier
                try! realmRepo.realm.write {
                    realmRepo.realm.add(photo)
                }
            }
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is where I store identifiers:

```
private var identifiers = [String]()
```

with actually 3 identifiers:

```
(lldb) po identifiers
▿ 3 elements
  - 0 : "106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473/L0/001"
  - 1 : "106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473/L0/001"
  - 2 : "B84E8479-475C-4727-A4A4-B77AA9980897/L0/001"
```

And here is how I try to retrieve them:

```
private func getImages() {
    photosToDisplay.removeAll()

    let options = PHFetchOptions()

    options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

    let results = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: self.identifiers, options: options)

    let manager = PHImageManager.default()

    results.enumerateObjects { (thisAsset, _, _) in

        manager.requestImage(for: thisAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 80.0), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil, resultHandler: {(thisImage, _) in

            self.photosToDisplay.append(UIImageView(image: thisImage))

        })
    }
    self.galleryCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

I have correctly added Privacy - Photo library usage description in info.plist and verified authorization with:

```
private func checkIfUserIsAllowToPickPhotoFromLibrary() {
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.denied || status == PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in
            if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                self.pickPhotoFromLibrary()
            } else {
                let alert = self.errorAlert.alert(message: "Invest'Immo a besoin d'avoir accès à votre bibliothèque photo. Sans ça vous ne pourrez pas choisir des photos de votre bibliothèque. S'il vous plait allez dans vos réglages et autorisez l'accès.")
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
        })
    } else if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
        pickPhotoFromLibrary()
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you add a print(thisImage) before             self.photosToDisplay.append(UIImageView(image: thisImage)) and post the output?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Did you solve it? @JohnM

Comment: Have you solve it? @George

Answer (score 0):

After Hours & Days of debugging i found the folowing solution which is related to device settings.

Go to Settings -> search for your app name & select it -> photos (you will see "Selected Photos" option selected) -> change selection to All Photos and then retry!